AWS - EC2 Root Volume Change with another root volume

I have an AWS ec2 instance deployed by laravel forge. This instance was created about 5 years ago. Recently, my app went down, forge starting saying there is no more space left on this device. I increased the disk space on aws console. I dont have my private forge key to SSH into this server to do the "sudo growpart" section. I added new key pairs, but it keeps giving me permission denied error when i try to ssh through terminal.

I thought i could create another instance and use this EBS volume as the root volume but this fails. SSH connection times out. No luck.

Third thing i tried was to attach this volume to another instance as an additional disk. This time, i could do Sudo lsblk and growpart since i've SSH access.


I'm stuck. Is there anyway i could get this main root volume working again on a new instance or even the original instance? If not, is it possible for me to access the data on this volume, I dont want to lose my app data (mysql db). What could i do?

Your #3 should work, increasing the volume size in the AWS console, then attaching to another instance to increase the partition size. Why didn't that work? Please edit your question to post detailed steps of what you did and include any error messages.

#3 did work but issue is that i still cant use that increased volume as my root as my root volume on a new instance. Instance is running but seems unresponsive.  Status check says "Instance reachability check failed" and i cant connect via SSH.

Unfortunately there's not much we can do to help with such a vague question. To process documented on the AWS website to increase volume size should work fine.
